# list of Items, bulk operation sample

Tags: reactjs

This might simple but I need some pointers.

I have a list of items which I am rendering using map list (Parent Component) and item(Child Component).

1. There is checkbox inside child component
2. Parent has a button

Now, I want user should able to select few or all items from the list, and on click of button we should highlight the checked items alone.

I tried some flag passing, however could not figure out best approach.

Please suggest.

Comment: create check state in parent & then pass it to child as parameter. on click of parent, change state & it'll get rendered in child too

Comment: Thank you, however will it render equal to number of children's or once?

Comment: you need to maintain state for each parent in child
then you can render it for each children

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.

Finally, figured out by adding operation code in parent component.

Child component just get status update in case.